# How to pull a specific commit from a remote branch?

Tags: git, svn, branch, bitbucket

How do I pull a specific commit (eg: with an id of 'xyz') to my local machine from a remote branch? Please note that since the commit of 'xyz', a few more commits were pushed to this branch.

Also, I am already on this remote branch and not the master.

The repo that I have only includes the master and the branch I want to pull from.

I'm aware there are many posts regarding this issue however none of them seem to focus specifically to my issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want to *pull* the commit? Not check it out?

Comment: Do you have any uncommited changes on your local branch and/or have you made any commits to your local branch that haven't been pushed to the remote?

Comment: @chamila-c Yes I do but I realized that I need to revert back to the 'xyz' commit and start from there.

Comment: Ok, and do you know the id (commit hash) of the last commit that you have in common with the remote (i.e. the last commit before you started making changes)?

Comment: @chamila-c Yes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your branch name is `<branchname>`, you could do something like:

```
# (Optionally) Save your work to a 'temp' branch, in case you want to come back to it:
git checkout -b temp
git add -A .
git commit -m "WIP"

# Get back to your branch, and reset it to 'xyz':
git checkout <branchname>
git fetch origin
git reset --hard xyz
```

At this point, your branch is now at 'xyz' as per the remote, and you can start afresh from there.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. My local directory has reverted back to the way it was during the 'xyz' commit. One further query... this won't have any effect on future commits I make to this branch, will it? Can I still commit and push to my remote branch the way I did previously? Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned that the remote had further commits after 'xyz', so if you now add your own commits (locally) after 'xyz', then your local branch will diverge from its remote. Once a local branch diverges from a remote one, you'll need to merge (or rebase) in order to push. Or you would need to force push, but that should only be a last resort, and only done if you understand all the implications.

Comment: Could you give me the steps to do this with `merge` and/or `rebase`? Just in a hypothetical scenario. Thanks.

Comment: That will really depend on how you want your changes after 'xyz' to integrate with the changes in the remote after 'xyz', but assuming you can cleanly merge, or know how to resolve any conflicts:

`git checkout -b mergesource`;
`git checkout <branchname>`;
`git fetch origin`;
`git reset --hard origin/<branchname>`;
`git merge mergesource`;
# If conflicts, need to resolve;
`git push origin <branchname>`;

Comment: Before you start messing with `rebase`, I strongly recommend you read up on it, and understand what it's doing, but for your specific case, you could:

`git fetch origin`;
`git rebase origin/<branchname>`;
# If conflicts, need to resolve
`git push origin <branchname>`

Comment: I'm relatively new to git in general so yes I will definitely be reading up on these concepts in details. Thank you so much for your help!